# MySQL Geo Location showing wrong distance

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using the below SQL query to fetch the distance of the each record form its longitude and latitude but can't understand why the distance for all records is showing same?

```
SELECT
 max(if(`field_name`='store-name', `field_value`, null )) AS `store-name`,
 max(if(`field_name`='store-description', `field_value`, null )) AS `store-description`,
 max(if(`field_name`='store-longitude', `field_value`, null )) AS `store-longitude`,
 max(if(`field_name`='store-latitude', `field_value`, null )) AS `store-latitude`,
 ((ACOS( SIN( -27.486204 * PI( ) /180 ) * SIN( 'store-latitude' * PI( ) /180 ) + COS( -27.486204 * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( 'store-latitude' * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( (152.994962 - 'store-longitude') * PI( ) /180 ) ) *180 / PI( )) *60 * 1.1515) AS `distance`
FROM `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` 
WHERE `form_name` = 'Add Store'  
GROUP BY `submit_time` 
ORDER BY `submit_time` DESC
LIMIT 0,100
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Use backticks (`), not single quotes (') around column names.... they're column names, not strings

Comment: Probably not a good idea to give people access to your database either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backticks (`), not single quotes (') around column names.... they're column names, not strings

```
SELECT *,
       ((ACOS( SIN( -27.486204 * PI( ) /180 ) * SIN( `store-latitude` * PI( ) /180 ) + COS( -27.486204 * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( `store-latitude` * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( (152.994962 - `store-longitude`) * PI( ) /180 ) ) *180 / PI( )) *60 * 1.1515) AS `distance`
   FROM ( SELECT
             max(if(`field_name`='store-name', `field_value`, null )) AS `store-name`,
             max(if(`field_name`='store-description', `field_value`, null )) AS `store-description`,
             max(if(`field_name`='store-longitude', `field_value`, null )) AS `store-longitude`,
             max(if(`field_name`='store-latitude', `field_value`, null )) AS `store-latitude`
        FROM `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` 
       WHERE `form_name` = 'Add Store'  
       GROUP BY `submit_time` 
       ORDER BY `submit_time` DESC
       ) A
LIMIT 0,100
```

Otherwise, MySQL will try to cast that quoted string to a numeric to do the multiplication, and treat it as 0

Comment: That return an error `#1054 - Unknown column 'store-latitude' in 'field list'` Can you please check the demo phpmyadmin link I mentioned in question.

Comment: Thanks a ton Mark, you are legend :)

Comment: There is an error in the formula that is easy to fix. Where you see the constant 1.1515 in the formula just replace it with 1.85509714, This will ensure that the result will be in the correct Metric/Kilometer rather than the outdated and stupid imperial/Miles. :P